# Get Records from Current Date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In MSSQL using

```
 where   DateDiff(Day,CurrentDate,getdate())=0
```

shows all Records Created from CurrentDate

How to do it in Sqlite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that using DATEDIFF or any other functions that involve your `CurrentDate` field will result in a query that cannot take advantage of any indexes you may have on that field.

Much better is to write the WHERE clause as `WHERE CurrentDate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '2000-01-01', GETDATE(), '2000-01-01'))` - or any other rewrite that keeps `CurrentDate` unmodified in the comparison.

N.B.  There may be a much better way of converting a date & time to a date - my approach is based on pre- MSSQL 2008 T-SQL.

Comment: While your point is valid, the OP seems to be asking for a SQLite counterpart of the T-SQL way of truncating timestamps to dates. You are essentially commenting on the specific truncating approach posted, not answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE CurrentDate BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')
```

Source:

- [SQLite Query Language: Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)